# TypeError: Result of expression 'dbMasterObject.updateIntoTestResult' [undefined] is not a function

Tags: c++, database, qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I am doing a database operations in my project. I have a file 'dataBaseMaster',which has a  function updateIntoTestResult(). I have created a dbMasterObject by setting context like this

`qml->setContextProperty("dbMasterObject", dbMasterObject);`

but when i try to call this updateIntoTestResult() method in my main.qml,i am getting an error like this

`TypeError: Result of expression 'dbMasterObject.updateIntoTestResult' [undefined] is not a function`

DatabaseMaster.hpp

```
  class DatabaseMaster : public QObject
{
public:
      Q_OBJECT
public:
    void updateIntoTestResult(int id, int result);

};
```

DatabaseMaster.cpp

```
void DatabaseMaster::updateIntoTestResult(int id, int result) {

QSqlDatabase database = QSqlDatabase::database();

QSqlQuery query(database);

query.prepare("update "+TEST_RESULT_MASTER+" set "+RESULT+" = :"+RESULT+" where "+TEST_ID+"= :"+TEST_ID+";");

query.bindValue(":"+RESULT, result);
query.bindValue(":"+TEST_ID, id);

query.exec();
```

calling in main.qml

```
dbMasterObject.updateIntoTestResult(MICROPHONE_ID, TEST_STATE_PASS)
```

please help me out, why am i getting this error whereas i have declared that method correctly.

Thanks in advance..!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`updateIntoTestResult` is not known to qml system because it's not a slot or `Q_INVOKABLE`.

Simple fix - insert `Q_INVOKABLE`:

```
class DatabaseMaster : public QObject
{
public:
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Q_INVOKABLE void updateIntoTestResult(int id, int result);
};
```